# How to take the square root of $BC$ where $BC^2$ equals $56-32\sqrt3$

Tags: trigonometry, roots, radicals

$BC^2$ equals $56-32\sqrt3$

what is the square root of BC?

The dimensions I used to get this far (and I confirmed that they are correct) are A,B,C, in a right triangle, where B is $\sqrt{(42-24\sqrt3)}$ and A is $2\sqrt2-\sqrt6$

I can simplify it down to $2\sqrt{(14-8\sqrt3)}$
but the answer is

something - $2\sqrt6$

All help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: You can take out an additional factor of $\sqrt2$, and then use Joseph's idea to simplify the square root of $7-4\sqrt3$.

Comment: I don't see how his works, since you cannot just split a square root into addition and subtraction. I am trying to get BC, i already have $BC^2$

Comment: I have edited your header to agree with what you appear to be asking for in the body of the post.  Please let me know if you intended something else.

Answer (score 3):

Write $BC = \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.  Then
$$BC^2 = (\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2 = a + b - 2\sqrt{ab} = 56 - 32\sqrt{3} = 56 - 2\sqrt{3 \cdot 16^2}.$$
Now, try to find $a$ and $b$ so that $a + b = 56$ and $a \cdot b = 3 \cdot 16^2$.

Comment: I got it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Working in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt3]$ we have $56-32\sqrt3=4(14-8\sqrt3)=2^2(a+b\sqrt3)^2$ which leads to the system $$a^2+3b^2=14\\ab=-4$$ whose solutions are
$$(a,b)=(\pm2\sqrt2,\mp\sqrt2), \left(\pm\sqrt6,\mp\frac{2\sqrt6}{3}\right)$$ Then do you have $$\boxed{[2(2\sqrt2-\sqrt6)]^2=56-32\sqrt3}$$ as you can verify.

I leave as a question if with the other solution $\left(\pm\sqrt6,\mp\dfrac{2\sqrt6}{3}\right)$ we also have $[2(\pm\sqrt6,\mp\frac{2\sqrt6}{3})]^2=56-32\sqrt3$

Comment: Why does the $4(14-8\sqrt3)$ change into $(a+b\sqrt)^2$? I understand the 4 = 2 squared but I don't understand how you can just square that.

Comment: If you want to have the square root of $a^2b$, the problem you have to solve is just the calculation of $\sqrt b$ and your solution will be $a\sqrt b$